# Can QCheck (OCaml property-based testing library) be used to perform exhaustive testing?

Tags: testing, ocaml, property-based-testing

Regarding the OCaml QCheck library (https://github.com/c-cube/qcheck),
say we have a *complete generator* `g: typ Gen.t` for a finite type `typ` or a finite subset `s: typ -> bool` of `typ`, is it possible (with or without resorting to hacky techniques and/or slight modification to the library itself) to perform an exhaustive test (thus a proof!) for a property e.g. forall `x` (s.t. `s x = true` in the case we are only interested in a subset), `prop x = true`, given `prop: typ -> bool` always return a value for either any value of the type or the subset we are interested in?

By a "complete generator", I don't have a concrete definition for it but something as the name suggests. Some examples include:

- `Gen.pure ()` for the type `unit`
- `Gen.int_bound 5` for the subset `fun x -> x >= 0 && x <= 5` of type `int`
- `` Gen.oneofl [`mon; `tue; `wed; `thu; `fri; `sat; `sun] `` for the type `` [`mon|`tue|`wed|`thu|`fri|`sat|`sun] ``

Answer (score 0):

In brief, this is possible but it is really unclear if it is desirable.

Indeed, you can define a qcheck generator from an exhaustive sequence

```
let make_gen seq =
  let current = ref seq in
  let rec gen state = match !current () with
    | Seq.Cons (x,seq) ->
      current := seq;
      x
    | Seq.Nil ->
      current := seq;
      gen state
  in
  let shrink _x () = Seq.Nil in
  QCheck2.Gen.make_primitive ~gen ~shrink
```

and use `Qcheck` runner to test properties on the total number of elements in this existing sequence.

However, it is then not clear what `Qcheck` brings you since you can not use any of the other `Qcheck` generators: even for a finite set, a random generator will require an infinite number of samples to almost surely cover all cases. Similarly, for an exhaustive generator, shrinking is not useful since you will have to test all values at some point.